# Do infinite while loops cause lag on their own thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a thread that reads from a serial port and writes to a `PipedOutputStream`. This way I can read from the port with scanners and such. I am wondering if code like this would slow down the JVM:

```
while (serialPort.isOpened()) {
    while (serialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount() > 0) {
        pipedOutputStream.write(serialPort.readBytes());
    }
}
```

While running in the first while loop, it would just be looping really fast until something comes in, should I add some delay there (like 10ms) so it isn't going so fast or does a while loop in this fashion not cause any noticeable lag?

The serial port does not have any `InputStreams` that I can read from, that is why I have to make this thread. I am using https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/ for my serial interface.

Comment: Find a way to wait for the actual event you are waiting for rather than spinning or sleeping. It's almost always possible

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation here it will likely help you develop a better notification based solution: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java#Event_Driven_Serial_Communication

Comment: I am using https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/, I should have mentioned that in my question.